# printing unsigned array and exiting the loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

**Summary**:

I want to be able to write a function that can let me store `10` values. I should be able to exit the loop with `0` without storing `0` to the array. I should be able to re-enter the array and keep storing until i get `10` values.

**Questions**:

1. I started to write something simple but when I store like `5` values it will print out the `5` values and then some random numbers. Why is that?
2. And how can I exit the loop without the array storing the `0`?

I'm quite new to this stuff so I hope I've followed the rules correctly here.

**Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arrayTable[9] = {0};
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Measurement #%i (or 0): ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arrayTable[i]);
        if (arrayTable[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arrayTable[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start, `int arrayTable[9]` cannot hold 10 values. Another thing, your output loop prints 10 values, even if you only enter 5 values. The rest will have undefined values, especially `arrayTable[9]` as mentioned. The second (output) loop, try `for (int j=0; j<i; j++) { printf("%d\n", arrayTable[j]); }`

Comment: will this effect say i wanted to calculate min,max and avg value? How can i only print the stored values without all the 0s?

Comment: @WeatherVane `int arrayTable[9] = {0};` initializes the whole array (9 values) to 0.

Comment: @MichaelWalz OK yes, the 10th is undefined.

Comment: @Alex your array is can hold 9 values, but are putting 10 values in it, therefore you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Alex unrelated to your problem, but you should be consistent and use `for (int i =...)` in both loops, mand remove the `int i;` before the first loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hi, the last loop helped me. But can you explain what you did? Why did we use another variable j?

Comment: @Alex I used another variable, so that the second loop could iterate as far as you got in the first loop. You exit the first loop at element `i` when the data is `0`. On the other hand, if there were no `0` values entered, `i` will be `10` after the first loop, so loop 2 will still behave nicely. Provided you increase the array size of course.

Comment: @Alex you want to store 10 values in a 9 size array (writing to outbounds), if you don't want 0 to be stored why you initialized elements to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you want discard 0 from array then use a temporary variable, input it, check whether it is a non-zero and if so store it to the element of array, if it is a zero exit the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int arrayTable[10] = {0};
    int iValue         = 0;
    int i              = 0;

    while(i < 10)
    {
         printf("Enter Measurement #%i (or 0): ", i+1);
         scanf("%d", &iValue); // input iValue

         if (!iValue) // if iValue is zero then exit loop without affecting array with this value
            break;
         else
        {
            arrayTable[i] = iValue; // if the value is non-zero store it in array and continue
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arrayTable[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: `else` not needed.  Good practice to check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ArraySize 10

int main(void){
    unsigned v, arrayTable[ArraySize] = {0};
    int n = 0;//number of elements

    while(n < ArraySize){
        printf("Enter Measurement #%i (or 0): ", n + 1);
        if(1 != scanf("%u", &v) || v == 0){//use other variable
            break;
        }
        arrayTable[n++] = v;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%u\n", arrayTable[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probbaly want this:

```
  ...
  int arrayTable[10] = {0};   // <<< [10] instead of [9]

  ...

  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      if (arrayTable[i] == 0) // <<< add this
        break;                // <<<

      printf("%d\n", arrayTable[i]);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: if i write all 10 values. it will print 11 values the last one being random number. How can i only print 10 values without the 11th value

Comment: @Alex I don't know how this code can print 11 values instead of 10. `for (i=0; i<10; i++)` will loop `i` from 0 to 9 and that's 10 values.

Comment: no you are right i was a bit unclear. i was referring to for the outside loop `(int j=0; j<i; j++) { printf("%d\n", arrayTable[j]); }` that Weather suggested. I dont want to print everytime i enter a value but rather i want to print everything out only when i call for it. EDIT sorry i did not print out a random 11th value, i must have looked at the code for too long! it does output correctly, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelWalz you are stroring 0 while exiting the loop